# Compute bounding sphere of sphere patch

Tags: 3d, geometry

Assume we have a sphere of radius R and are given a patch on this sphere with starting angles phi and theta and sweep angles phi_len and theta_len. The patch is defined as the surface on the sphere for all angles inside [phi, phi + phi_len] and [theta, theta + theta_len].

I'd like to compute a minimal bounding sphere of this patch in 3D cooridnates, i.e. center (x, y, z) and radius r so that the patch above is fully contained in the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 ideas:

ONE: Lets `p1= [x1,y1,z1]` is point where patch starts, and `p2= [x2,y2,z2]` is point for `angle_max = max(phi_len, theta_len)`.

For case when `angle_max<=PI` minimal sphere will have center in

```
c = p1+(p2-p1)/2
```

and radius half of distance between `p1` and `p2`:

```
r = |p2-p1|/2
```

For case if `PI<angle_max<=2PI` minimal sphere is full sphere with radius R.

SECOND: Lets `p1= [x1,y1,z1]` is point where patch starts, `p2= [x2,y2,z2]` is point for angles `phi` and `theta_len`, `p3= [x3,y3,z3]` is point for angles `phi_len` and `theta`. Let `angle_max = max(phi_len, theta_len)` then in case `angle_max<=PI` the minimum sphere is described by its equator which is [Circumscribed circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle) on triangle p1,p2,p3. For case  `PI<angle_max<=2PI` minimal sphere is full sphere with radius R.

Comment: That's not true, example: phi=theta=0, phi_len=2*PI, and theta_len=PI. Obviously, this patch covers the entire sphere surface, but your points p1 and p2 would be identical.

Comment: Probably my question was not precise enough. I meant patch not path. I will fix the question.

Comment: @user3612643 I see that my previous answer was correct, but you change the question so I update my answer again

Comment: I wrote "patch" in the original question, but thought you understood "path". This is why I clarified.

Comment: @user3612643  ok